# How to make release version of UWP package if release is not visible?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I am try to publish my application UWP Xamarin.Forms based application. Application is make with .NET standard(2.0.3).
When I try to make package in that there is one major issue I facing and that is I am not able to see `Release(x86)` option is visible there in `x86` format but `Release(x64)` option is visible there in `x64` format.

When I try to make new sample project and try to make `app packages` in that `Release(x86)` option is visible.
[image: In my project issue only this option are visible]

I also try with upgrade my nuget packages but that doesn't works for me.

Is anyone please suggest me?

Comment: No my startup project is MyProject.UWP but than also doesn't works for me.

Comment: Could you share the content of  **Yourapp.UWP.csproj** file?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT No I am not able to share. Can you please give some other way to solve that?

Comment: Please check if  the content of `csproj` file contain this line `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">`?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks for response. I checked my .csproj file. In that inside `<PropertyGroup></PropertyGroup>`. This line are write.
`<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>`
Please look into this and let me know what should I do.

Comment: Please try add the `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
  <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
  <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
  <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
</PropertyGroup>`  to the file.

Comment: Have you solved this issue ?

Comment: I try with them but in that I get compile time error. So I put my last code in that. Is there any other option.

Comment: You could create a bank uwp app and compare them to detect the missing `PropertyGroup`.